# What has better performance, double parallel query or query and then array.reduce? MongoDB and JavaScript Performance

Tags: mongodb

I want to know, in the long run, what option has better performance, assuming that DB is full of documents (may be thousands).

**1.Does two queries in parallel:**

The first query gets all rooms properties that user is in.
The second query gets a list of different rooms where user is in and each room has sharing property set to true.

```
const roomsInfo = await Promise.all([
  db.collection('rooms').find({'users.userId': user.userId}).toArray()
  db.collection('rooms').distinct('users.id', {'users.id': "myuserId", share: true}),
])
```

Example output:

```
roomsInfo[0] = [{
 "id": "room1",
 "name": "room1name",
 "data": "XXXX",
 "users" [{
    "id": "User1",
    "data": "XXXX",
  },{
    "id": "User2",
    "data": "XXXX",
  }],
  share: true
}, {
 "id": "room2",
  ...
  "share": true
},{
 "id": "room3",
  ...
  "share": false
},{
 "id": "room4",
  ...
  "share": false
}]

roomsInfo[1] = ["room1", "room2"]
```

**2.Does one query and then reduces:**

```
const roomInfo = await db.collection('rooms').find({'users.id': "myuserId"}).toArray()

const roomFiltered = roomInfo.reduce((a, o) => (o.share && a.push(o.id), a), [])
```

Second option has same result as first one

```
 (2nd option) roomInfo = roomInfo[0] (1st option)
 (2nd option) roomFiltered = roomInfo[1] (1st option)
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it with 100.000, 500.000 and 1M documents using [mgodatagen](https://github.com/feliixx/mgodatagen) and my conclusions are:

1. Queries in parallel are better than query and filter, map, reduce or any other array.method for big data.
2. When you've big data in your database you just query by index. If not you won't have any result in a reasonable time.
3. Divide your queries as many as you can: for example, if you query all rooms documents with a given array of rooms Id's, and rooms are divided in 2 types (single and group), is better to do 2 parallel queries first finding all single rooms that correspond to given array and second, all group rooms that correspond to given array.

Answer (score 0):

I think to use the first solution (two queries in parallel)
for example, you have 1000000 records in your DB , speed of MongoDB for distinct query is faster than of your local for loop